# input:focus isn't working on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, input

I have the following style which I've verified is being loaded:

```
input:focus { outline: none; }
:focus { outline: none; }
```

I did this to stop showing the dotted rectangle when I click on something.  This works for everything in FireFox that I've noticed, except for my input buttons.  My input buttons still show a dotted rectangle around them when I click them.

How can I get them to stop doing that?

Comment: I tried this with FireFox 3.5, and it looks like the outline settings are drawn around the button.  The button text has its own dotted outline.  Correct me if I'm wrong: you're trying to control the button text outline via CSS.  I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: @David Thanks, that might be the answer then.  I'm not actually using any text in the button (I'm using image instead), so I see a tiny little rectangle that's really annoying.  I wish there was a way to get rid of it, but oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to do this ([source](http://snipplr.com/view/28964/remove-button-focus-border-in-firefox-and-ie8-with-css/)):

```
/*for FireFox*/
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner { border : 0px; }

/*for IE8 */
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus { outline : none; }
```

I already had "outline: 0" set on everything via a reset, but that -moz-focus-inner was needed to get rid of the dotted line on a CSS-styled button.

Answer (score 2):

`<input ... onfocus="this.blur();"/>` will do the trick

or jQuery :

```
$("input").focus(function(){this.blur();});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (tried it in both firefox 2 and 3)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
   :focus { -moz-outline-style: none;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <input type="image" src="button.png" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just add a button.png :-)